# Complex selecting with nan values

Tags: python, dataframe, select, nan

I have a problem selecting with loc the frames that have NaN values. This is the function that I use.

```
def replace_nan(df, di):
    df.fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    for key, value in di.items():

        df.loc[   (df["meter_id"]==key) & (df["Values"]== np.nan),  "Values"]=value

return df
```

I already check that the NaN values are np.nan values, in this case I need to replace all NaN values in Values column and having in mind some categories in other column meter_id.

I want to know how to deal with that without replace the nan, because my solution was replace the nan with -1, also change the condition df["Values"]== -1 and the functon works without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get nan values out by:

```
     df = df.loc[df['Values'].isnull()]
```

This will get all of the rows where "Values" is nan